# How to print a tree on levels, given a struct that holds the value of the node and the value of it's parent, for each node in the tree

Tags: c++, tree

I have an array, where the index is the data of the node, and the value at that index is the parent of that node.

array = {2, 7, 5, 2, 7, 7, -1, 5, 2}
data ----  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9

I have to print this array as such:

```
7  
 2
  1
  4
  9
 5
  3
  8
 6
```

I have a struct that has the data from the array in two fields, value and parent, and than i created an array of t that holds those attributes for each node in the tree.

```
struct t{
    int value;
    int parent;
};
t tree[n];
```

Here is what I came up with for now. This prints the nodes in the correct order, but I have no idea how to add the spaces (" "), in order to highlight the levels of the tree. I hope you guys can give me some ideas.

```
void preetyPrint(t tree[], int n, int root)
{
    cout << root;
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (tree[i].parent == root)
        {
            preetyPrint(tree, n, tree[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry about the ambiguity of this question, I'm new here. Still learning to post good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to this:

### The `int depth` approach

You need to pass one more parameter to your function, an `int depth`.

When you call it from outside code, pass `0` for depth.

Then, in the recursive call inside `prettyPrint()`, invoke with `depth + 1`.

Then, in your `cout << root;` replace it with `cout << spaces << root;`

And add some code which computes a `spaces` string to consist of a number of space characters.  The number of spaces should be `depth` multiplied by  whatever you want your indentation to be. (Say, 2, or 4.) The calculation of the `spaces` string is left as an exercise to the reader.

### The `string indentation` approach

You need to pass one more parameter to your function, a `string indentation`.

When you call it from outside code, pass an empty string.

Then, in the recursive call inside `prettyPrint()`, invoke with `indentation + "  "` (assuming that you want each indentation level to be 2 characters wide.)

Then, in your `cout << root;` replace it with `cout << indentation << root;`

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I'm totally baffled that I didn't come up with the indentation approach myself, it was so simple.